# MPAndroidChart click listener on chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and would like to know how to perform click event on following graphs and get the related callback:
Pie chart: click on particular reason open its detail.
Bar chart: click on any bar open its detail.
Stacked Bar chart: click on any bar open its detail.

I need to **get notified when the chart is clicked**.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `OnChartValueSelectedListener`. You can find the documentation on how to implement it [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

This listener allows you to react on click gestures performed on the charts.

Comment: Also, just in case one only wants to trigger clicks and not finger swipes or drags you will need to make sure to disable this chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false); Otherwise this listener will trigger if you swipe through the bars.

Comment: @Philip i want to show one dialogue with  card if the user clicks on the graph how can i do this ? `<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp" />` this is my graph view. This is inside a card view and i call everything on a fragment. Actually i want to show some details about tha graph how can i do this ?

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda, How to detect whether the graph has finished scrolling. I am not asking about the end of the graph. When we scroll, how can we detect that the scroll event of the graph is finished ?

Comment: onChartGestureEnd(...) could be a start, but it could be that this already triggers when you lift your finger and not when the scrolling actually ends

Answer (score 11):

for LineChart

```
   chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)
        {
            float x=e.getX();
            float y=e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected()
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

for LineChart if you are using displayed **non float value in Kotlin** use below code

```
lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(object : OnChartValueSelectedListener 
       {
        override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry, h: Highlight?) {
            val x = e.x.toString()
            val y = e.y
            val selectedXAxisCount = x.substringBefore(".") //this value is float so use substringbefore method
            // another method shown below
            val nonFloat=lineChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.x)
            //if you are display any string in x axis you will get this
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected() {}
    })
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 3):

```
For PieChart :- 
mPieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(object : 
OnChartValueSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected() {
            }

            override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {

                val pieEntry = e as PieEntry
                val label: String = pieEntry.label
            }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement `OnChartValueSelectedListener`
2. Register listener in activity/fragment
3. override methods
4. This is in Kotlin

   ```
   chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)

   override fun onNothingSelected() {
       Log.i("Entry selected", "Nothing selected.")
   }

   override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
       Log.i("Entry selected", e.toString())
       val x:Float =e!!.x
       val y:Float =e!!.y
       chart.highlightValue(h)

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement interface `OnChartValueSelectedListener`
2. Implemented methods

```java
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
   // enter your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
    // do nothing
}
```

3. Add this code to your chart display method

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
```